# Parsing classes for methods with custom attribute and adding to delegate list

Tags: c#, attributes, delegates

I need help parsing specific methods from classes derived from a base class and add them to a delegate collection.

I have a bunch of classes that are derives from a single base class. Each of those classes have 1 or more methods with a specific custom attribute [IntentHandler]. Those methods all have a single parameter. The parameter type is different depending on the method, but each method's parameter is derived from another base class (public class Intent). I need to find all those methods, create an appropriate delegate and add them to a delegate "Dictionary" where the key is the parameter's type, and the value is the method.

Right now, I have each subclass creating and registering it's method delegate, but there are a LOT of sub classes, each requiring the code to register it's methods. I would rather handle this through the base class using System.Reflection I believe. It would greatly reduce code and allow for better expansion later.

```
public class StaticService : Service
{
    delegate void ObjectCreatedIntentHandler(ObjectCreatedIntent oci);

    private ObjectCreatedIntentHandler handleObjectCreatedIntent;

    public StaticService()
    {
        handleObjectCreatedIntent = HandleObjectCreatedIntent;
    }

    private void HandleObjectCreatedIntent(ObjectCreatedIntent oci)
    {

    }

    internal override void RegisterIntentHandlers(IntentManager registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterForIntent(typeof(ObjectCreatedIntent), handleObjectCreatedIntent);
    }

    internal override void UnregisterIntentHandlers(IntentManager registry)
    {
        registry.UnregisterForIntent(typeof(ObjectCreatedIntent), handleObjectCreatedIntent);
    }
}
```

I would prefer something more along the lines of:

```
public class StaticService : Service
{
    public StaticService()
    {
    }

    [IntentHandler]
    private void HandleObjectCreatedIntent(ObjectCreatedIntent oci)
    {

    }
}
```

and the base class

```
public class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        RegisterIntents()
    }

    private void RegisterIntents()
    {
        // Find all classes derived from Service
        // Find each method in those classes with the [IntentHandler]
        // Attribute
        // Get the method's Intent Class derived parameter type
        // create a delegate I can invoke later for that method.
        // Add the delegate to a Dictionary<Intent,Delegate>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will be easier to define the `base` class as a generic class and call the base ctor and methods registrations from each child class. This way you won't need to use reflection and also avoid `typeof` operator at registration calls

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I am using Action now instead of a Delegate.

In my base class, I am now doing this:

```
    internal void RegisterIntentHandlers(IntentManager registry)
    {
        RegisterIntentHandlers(this.GetType(), registry);
    }

    internal void RegisterIntentHandlers(Type klass, IntentManager registry)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo m in klass.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            foreach (Attribute attribute in m.GetCustomAttributes())
            {
                if (attribute is IntentHandler)
                {
                    if (m.GetParameters().Count() == 1)
                    {
                        ParameterInfo p = m.GetParameters()[0];
                        Type paramClass = p.ParameterType;
                        if (paramClass.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Intent)))
                        {
                            object consumerKey = this.GetType().FullName + "#" + m.Name;
                            Action<Intent> intentConsumer = (Action<Intent>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Intent>), this);
                            registry.RegisterForIntent<Intent>(paramClass, consumerKey, intentConsumer);
                            if (!registration.ContainsKey(paramClass))
                                registration[paramClass].Add(consumerKey);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't finished testing yet, but it looks right to me. I have to go cleanup all the subclasses now before I can finish testing.

Any opinions/suggestions?

Comment: Now I am having an issue with the CreateDelegate statement:
   Action<Intent> intentConsumer = (Action<Intent>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Intent>), this);

"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."  So obviously an issue of type casting from Action<?> to Action<Intent>. Suggestions?